# not able to access other java class from applet class

Tags: java, applet

I have created an applet class(`app.java`) and on button click event I am trying to create a java object for `test.java` class.

But not able to create one and code throws `classnotfoundexception`.

`Test.java` is in same jar as App.java and also in same package.

I have included all my dependencies for `test.java` in applet archive tag.

Am I missing something more?

Comment: As the @MadProgrammer would say, you should try to avoid using Applets because they are deprecated.  That being said, you should also show us a snapshot of your project layout.

Comment: You need to post part of your code that's having problem so that community can take a look and suggest a solution

Comment: *"..all my dependencies for `test.java`.."* At time of deployment, Java source files are utterly irrelevant. We need to focus on `.class` files. 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).